# Installing laravel collective doesn't work?

Tags: laravel, forms

My laravel version 5.7.8 I am trying to install the last Laravel Collective, using this code:

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0"
```

But it doesn't work, why?

This is my code in contact view page:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'contact/submit']) !!}
<div class="form-group">   
  {{Form::label('name', 'Name')}}                            
  {{Form::label('name', 'Enter your name')}}               
</div>
<div class="form-group">   
  {{Form::label('email', 'E-Mail Address')}}                 
  {{Form::label('email', 'example yourgmail@gmail.com')}}    
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: "Butnot work why?" - Could you explain what is not working? What's the exact error or behaviour?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: hi, mr marcin, when i create input box for user name and password in the follow image the code view as text no place to add the input. check this please    https://prnt.sc/l44kmz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running Laravel in the latest version, which is 5.7.*, it is possible the laravelcollective/html package is not up to date. Therefor you could check out the latest version, which is *5.7.1*.

Reference: [Packagist laravel/collectivehtml](https://packagist.org/packages/laravelcollective/html)

If that doesn't help you have a look at your providers under *config/app.php*
You need to got the following entry into your providers array

```
 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
```

so the full array looks like

```
 'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

    /*
     * Package Service Providers...
     */


    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,


    /*
     * Collective Providers
     */
    'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider', //Your Provider here 

    /*
     * Third Party Providers
     */

   ],
```

Next step would be to check if the aliases for the collective are set up correctly in the same file (*config/app.php*)

```
  'aliases' => [
// ...
  'Form' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
  'Html' => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',
// ...
],
```

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: thank you that dit it for me ! Couldn't find an up to date information, since their website show only until 5.4, I wonder why they don't keep their website updated anymore...

Answer (score 4):

**There is no problem in your code**, I assume that you have forgotten any step to during installation time

I will start with the initial stage how to use laravelcollective/html package

---

Begin by installing this package through Composer. Edit your project's `composer.json` file to require *laravelcollective/html*

```
"require": {
    "laravelcollective/html": "*"
}
```

**Note**: This will download the latest version of the *laravelcollective/html* package

Next, update Composer from the Terminal:

```
composer update
```

Next, add your new provider to the *providers* array of `config/app.php`:

```
  'providers' => [
    // ...
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

add two class aliases to the *aliases* array of `config/app.php:`

```
  'aliases' => [
    // ...
      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

---

Now put your code in the view file and check in the browser no longer will get error

Answer (score 0):

i solve this :
1-

```
  composer require laravelcollective/html
```

"i find it in packagist"
2-IN LARAVEL PROJECT

```
CONFIG/app.php:
'providers' => [
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class, 
],
```

"i add line of code at the end of providers and don't toch anything else" 
3-IN LARAVEL PROJECT
  CONFIG/app.php:

```
    'aliases' => [
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
        'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
],
```

4-on cmd or gitbash

```
composer update
```

"this will use internet resource!"
5- in cmd or git bash

```
php artisan serve
```

6- check form on web browser

Answer (score 0):

If you use LaravelCollection version 5.7 or newer, the only thing you need to do is run

```
composer require laravelcollective/html
```

and you are good to go.